# How to pass parameters in where clause to static web method in c# asp.net using jquery/ajax?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I need to pass `label` value to `static` 'web method' in `where` clause using `ajax`. I am creating a structured chart where, i need to show only data and sub data of users who have currently logged in.
i am not getting any idea of how to pass asp controls value to static method.i have even tried to pass label value from `jquery` and `ajax` but, i am getting **`undefined error`**.please help to solve this error
My **code** is

```
       [WebMethod]
        public static List<object> GetChartData(string name)
        {
        string query = "SELECT * ";
        query += " from abc  where ID=@ID";
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr1"].ConnectionString;
        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr))
        {

            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query))
            {
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",name);
              ----i am getting error on lblsubid----

                List<object> chartData = new List<object>();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (MySqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        chartData.Add(new object[]
                        {
                     sdr["ID"], sdr["Name"], sdr["Emailid"] ,sdr["SubId"] 
                        });
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
                return chartData;
                 }
                }
               }
```

frontend code :-

```
          google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["orgchart"] });
          google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
          function drawChart() { 
         var url = window.location.pathname;
        var action = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        document.getElementById("lblsubid").innerHTML = action;          
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Test.aspx/"+action+"GetChartData",
            data: '{name: "' + action + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {                 
                var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
                data.addColumn('string', 'Entity');
                data.addColumn('string', 'ParentEntity');
                data.addColumn('string', 'ToolTip');
                for (var i = 0; i < r.d.length; i++) {
                    var employeeId = r.d[i][0].toString();
                    var employeeName = r.d[i][1];
                    var designation = r.d[i][2];
                    var reportingManager = r.d[i][3] != null ? r.d[i][3].toString() : '';
                    data.addRows([[{
                        v: employeeId,
                        f: employeeName + '<div>(<span>' + designation + '</span>)</div>'
                    }, reportingManager, designation]]);
                }
                var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart($("#chart")[0]);
                chart.draw(data, { allowHtml: true });

            },
            failure: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);
            },
            error: function (r) {
                alert(r.d);
            }

            });
             }
          </script>
             <div id="chart">
             </div>
              <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblsubid"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: You have to return a string. As far as the label...i don't see a label. Research Page Methods.

Comment: Where your `label` in your AJAX call? You would need to set a value to the label and then send it to your WebMethod.

Answer (score -1):

In your ajax call to your WebMethod you are not passing in anything

You need to pass in your label text

```
 data: '{}', -- your label value here
```

And in your method: (add parameters)

```
[WebMethod]
 public static List<object> GetChartData(string LabelText)
```

And when building your query:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",LabelText);
```

Comment: thank u everyone for your help..i did it from using session